# Could Someone Explain These Steps? Especially the Each Ratio Part.

Tags: algebras

[Could you explain the steps, especially the each ratio= sum of numerators/sum of denominators part.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFC7w.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because is,

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} = \frac{e}{f}$$

then,

> $$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} = \frac{e}{f} = \frac{a+c+e}{b+d+f}$$

---

This can be proved as follows.

Let $$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} = \frac{e}{f} = r$$

$$\implies a = rb, c = rd, e = rf$$

$$\frac{a+c+e}{b+d+f} = \frac{r(b+d+f)}{b+d+f} = r$$

So, $$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} = \frac{e}{f} = \frac{a+c+e}{b+d+f}$$

Here, $$r = \frac{y+x+y+y}{x-z+z+y} = \frac{2(x+y)}{x+y} = 2, (x+y\not=0)$$

Compare $r$ with every fraction and obtain $x:y:z$

Comment: Is this the same for a/b = c/d = e/f = a-c-e/b-d-f?

Comment: Yes you're correct ***but be sure it's not zero*** as $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined. For e.g, $\frac{3}{4} = \frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2} =0.5$ but $ \frac{3-2-1}{6-4-2} = \frac{0}{0}$ is undefined.

Comment: Is it similar for $$a/b + c/d + e/f = g/h + i/j + k/l$$ where it is equal to $$a+c+e+g+i+k/b+d+f+h+j+l$$

Comment: Yes here too the **sum shouldn't be equal to zero**, they've mentioned this in the solution by saying it is true unless $x+y = 0$